# VBS Script for Windows Update

Tags: windows, vbscript, windows-update

How would I remove the users request to "approve" everything in this .VBS script and instead just let it autorun/install everything found?

***Details on how the script runs:***

This .VBS script here runs on the Windows computer, searchs for Windows Update, then manually ask the user to "okay" each update it finds. Once the user hits "okay" and accepts the updates found, it then downloads it.

Once the Widnows Updates downloads, it then asks the user again to approve each Windows Update install. Which is not automated..... I'm not familiar with .VBS enough to edit this script.

```
Set updateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
updateSession.ClientApplicationID = "MSDN Sample Script"

Set updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()

WScript.Echo "Searching for updates..." & vbCRLF

Set searchResult = _
updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software' and IsHidden=0")

WScript.Echo "List of applicable items on the machine:"

For I = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
    WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> " & update.Title
Next

If searchResult.Updates.Count = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "There are no applicable updates."
    WScript.Quit
End If

WScript.Echo vbCRLF & "Creating collection of updates to download:"

Set updatesToDownload = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl")

For I = 0 to searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
    addThisUpdate = false
    If update.InstallationBehavior.CanRequestUserInput = true Then
        WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> skipping: " & update.Title & _
        " because it requires user input"
    Else
        If update.EulaAccepted = false Then
            WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> note: " & update.Title & _
            " has a license agreement that must be accepted:"
            WScript.Echo update.EulaText
            WScript.Echo "Do you accept this license agreement? (Y/N)"
            strInput = WScript.StdIn.Readline
            WScript.Echo 
            If (strInput = "Y" or strInput = "y") Then
                update.AcceptEula()
                addThisUpdate = true
            Else
                WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> skipping: " & update.Title & _
                " because the license agreement was declined"
            End If
        Else
            addThisUpdate = true
        End If
    End If
    If addThisUpdate = true Then
        WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> adding: " & update.Title 
        updatesToDownload.Add(update)
    End If
Next

If updatesToDownload.Count = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "All applicable updates were skipped."
    WScript.Quit
End If

WScript.Echo vbCRLF & "Downloading updates..."

Set downloader = updateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader() 
downloader.Updates = updatesToDownload
downloader.Download()

Set updatesToInstall = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl")

rebootMayBeRequired = false

WScript.Echo vbCRLF & "Successfully downloaded updates:"

For I = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count-1
    set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(I)
    If update.IsDownloaded = true Then
        WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> " & update.Title 
        updatesToInstall.Add(update) 
        If update.InstallationBehavior.RebootBehavior > 0 Then
            rebootMayBeRequired = true
        End If
    End If
Next

If updatesToInstall.Count = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "No updates were successfully downloaded."
    WScript.Quit
End If

If rebootMayBeRequired = true Then
    WScript.Echo vbCRLF & "These updates may require a reboot."
End If

WScript.Echo  vbCRLF & "Would you like to install updates now? (Y/N)"
strInput = WScript.StdIn.Readline
WScript.Echo 

If (strInput = "Y" or strInput = "y") Then
    WScript.Echo "Installing updates..."
    Set installer = updateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller()
    installer.Updates = updatesToInstall
    Set installationResult = installer.Install()

    'Output results of install
    WScript.Echo "Installation Result: " & _
    installationResult.ResultCode 
    WScript.Echo "Reboot Required: " & _ 
    installationResult.RebootRequired & vbCRLF 
    WScript.Echo "Listing of updates installed " & _
    "and individual installation results:" 

    For I = 0 to updatesToInstall.Count - 1
        WScript.Echo I + 1 & "> " & _
        updatesToInstall.Item(i).Title & _
        ": " & installationResult.GetUpdateResult(i).ResultCode   
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Did you mean run it without echo message ? i mean it dosen't interact with the user ?

Comment: @Hackoo right now this script does interact with the user. It asks the user to "approve" each update. Which leads to 30 pop ups, I'm trying to remove the users interaction and let it run without approval. Just auto-approve everything found and install it. Thanks for checking it out man!

Comment: @Hackoo I misunderstood your question. I want it to run without the echo message. You’re correct. It does interact, although I do not want it to interact.

Comment: You should in this case comments each line begin with wscript.echo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Script output** via `WScript.Echo` method: [run your script using the command-line-based script host](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490816.aspx) (e.g. `Cscript.exe YourScript.vbs`).
2. **User input**: replace `strInput = WScript.StdIn.Readline` with `strInput = "Y"` (all occurrences in your script).
3. **To keep update log**: use `Cscript.exe YourScript.vbs > YourLog.txt`.

Explanation:

1. Whether you use `WScript` or `CScript`, you still run the scripts in the same manner. The difference is only in the output — `WScript` generates windowed output, while `CScript` sends its output to the command window in which it was started. On initial installation, the default host is `WScript`. To change it to `CScript`, type the following at the command line: `cscript //h:cscript`.
2. I'd not use `Cscript.exe YourScript.vbs < Prepared-Y.txt` redirection: we don't know number of `Y` lines in input file as we can't estimate number of updates in advance; could lead to an error `Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Input past end of file`
3. Read [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: this is working correctly, I've used WScript for the output. Thank you for your hard work!